# Efficient way to create the probability distribution of a list of numbers with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, probability-distribution

This is an example of what I am trying to do. Suppose the following numpy array:

```
A = np.array([3, 0, 1, 5, 7]) # in practice, this array is a huge array of float numbers: A.shape[0] >= 1000000
```

I need the fastest possible way to get the following result:

```
result = []

for a in A:
    result.append( 1 / np.exp(A - a).sum() )

result = np.array(result)

print(result)

>>> [1.58297157e-02 7.88115138e-04 2.14231906e-03 1.16966657e-01 8.64273193e-01]
```

Option 1 (faster than previous code):

```
result = 1 / np.exp(A - A[:,None]).sum(axis=1)

print(result)

>>> [1.58297157e-02 7.88115138e-04 2.14231906e-03 1.16966657e-01 8.64273193e-01]
```

Is there a faster way to get "result" ?

Comment: To be clear: the goal is that the values in `result` sum to 1, and each is proportional to e to the power of the corresponding original value?

Comment: Yes. result sum to 1. But I cannot directly do the exponentials because the values in A are very large

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.softmax.html

Comment: "But I cannot directly do the exponentials because the values in A are very large" Oh, I answered too quickly, then. Are they within some small range of each other? Can you subtract a constant offset first?

Comment: @j1-lee yes, the softmax function !

Comment: @Karl Knechtel I am going to try scipy.special.softmax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes: scipy.special.softmax did the trick

```
from scipy.special import softmax

result = softmax(A)
```

Thank you @j1-lee and @Karl Knechtel

Answer (score 3):

Rather than trying to compute each value by normalizing it in place (effectively adding up all the values, *repeatedly for each* value), instead just get the exponentials and then normalize once at the end. So:

```
raw = np.exp(A)
result = A / sum(A)
```

(In my testing, the builtin `sum` is over 2.5x as fast as `np.sum` for summing a small array. I did not test with larger ones.)

Comment: I cannot do np.exp(A) because the values in A are huge for np.exp; it gives me an overflow. scipy.special.softmax handle that issue. Thank you.